# jQuery Parallax not scrolling after click event changes height of other element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parallax.js

I am using Parallax.js in my wordpress site. On one of my pages, I have a click event and when its executed it adds a class to an element (not the parallax element) which adds height to the non-parallax element. anyways when its executed my parallax stops scrolling.

I have tried re-triggering the parallax on my click events and that did not work.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(e){
    $(".section1").addClass("toggle");
    return false;
});
```

And here is my css

```
.section1 {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height 1.00s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.toggle{
    max-height: 5000px;
    transition: max-height 1.30s ease-in;
}
```

and my html of the parallax:

```
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-stretch-content="true" data-vc-parallax="1.5" data-vc-parallax-o-fade="on" data-vc-parallax-image="http://new.sekanskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/windows-walls-floors.jpg" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid what-we-do-service vc_row-has-fill vc_row-no-padding vc_general vc_parallax vc_parallax-content-moving-fade js-vc_parallax-o-fade" style="position: relative; left: -155px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1440px;"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 skrollable skrollable-before" data-5p-top-bottom="opacity:0;" data-30p-top-bottom="opacity:1;" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper"></div></div></div><div class="vc_parallax-inner skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="top: -50%;" data-top-bottom="top: 0%;" style="height: 150%; background-image: url(&quot;http://new.sekanskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/windows-walls-floors.jpg&quot;); top: -36.3243%;"></div></div>
```

And here is what I tried to re-trigger the parallax:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(e){
    $(".section1").addClass("toggle");
        $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
    return false;
});
```

What I am expecting the parallax to be able to continue be able to scroll after my click event is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using old and unmaintained parallax library.

If you cannot use some other library, you need to change the code in this file `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax/master/scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js`.
You would have to add this custom event listener to the parallax constructor (`$.fn.parallax`):

```
// [...]
$window.bind('parallax-refresh', function (){
    $this.each(function() {
        firstTop = $this.offset().top;
    });
});
// [...]
```

And then trigger the event back in main script:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(e){
    $(".section1").addClass("toggle").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        $(window).trigger('parallax-refresh');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That did not work, this is a wordpress site using wpbakery to build the page.

Comment: Here is the site in question with the issue. This has your code applied. http://new.sekanskin.com/what-we-do/

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: I updated my parallax.min.js file, but that did not work.